# how is hot reload supposed to work in react native?

Tags: react-native, redux

Hot Reloading is out now but I am having lots of problems getting it to work.

At first I had the standard `module.hot.accept("../reducers", () => {` code in my redux store but that was causing problems. After commenting that code out I started getting `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.

I created a new project `react-native init test` and I get the same error every time a file is changed.

```
ExceptionsManager.js:61 Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Is there something that needs to be done in the project to make hot reloading work?

**Update**

This is still undocumented and causing more problems than its worth. For now I am using redux-persist with live reloading.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix to this problem? It's happening with my project as well. When I save a new bit of code it will then say `cannot read property length of undefined`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Facebook has finally documented how to use Hot Reloading or Hot Module Replacement.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2016/03/24/introducing-hot-reloading.html

The api is slightly different than Webpack

```
if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept(() => {
        const nextRootReducer = require("../reducers").default;
        store.replaceReducer(nextRootReducer);
    });
}
```